# Kotlin (Spring boot) - Error creating bean with name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I hope you can help me solve a problem, I am starting a project with spring boot (kotlin).Java 8

I have 2 similar codes with the same base of repositories, but one of them does not work send me an error that says "**Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosController'**"

[code that does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gXgy.png)

[code that does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sIOf.png)

I do not understand why the one in the first image does not work , if the only thing that changed was that instead of "*AGE*" I would look for "*CVE_ENTIDAD*".

for more details I attach the 2 projects and their tables.
[projects](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmSd8TqT7gqZgRzm0jbpeFI49mI7)

First of all thank you ...

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=50814:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks\out\production\classes;C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks\out\production\resources;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.0.5.RELEASE\c99b58e8ada11478aa5d0c3065745b7e887f094e\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.0.5.RELEASE\52daa1f1509bd637a737206e54c06a17aabb9504\spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-kotlin\2.9.6\12c5482762e03c19a95187fd94c3611738dee604\jackson-module-kotlin-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.2.51\68faa6fb7e32a7665a6849f242bc621c3ed48101\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.51.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.2.51\36b719a7b84452dd13eeec979d8c82bfb765c57d\kotlin-reflect-1.2.51.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.0.5.RELEASE\6bc1e8bcc849772d48cae1e8278cd2b471361698\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.0.5.RELEASE\9a5370acc7c5e17f4a00578211fbbd212b9a8329\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.0.5.RELEASE\d0052ded4733ceb1fb7d927238f22f9a92099227\spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.47\9de4159aaf2d08817a276610b8114a825fca6cfd\mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.5.RELEASE\1f53487a373be18d064a5815e9bac9882ef15cdc\spring-boot-starter-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\d81aff979d603edd90dcd8db2abc1f4ce6479e3e\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.17.Final\f2dc36470e7a2ffcf6106bb1625ecf5b54bb5f65\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-jpa\2.0.10.RELEASE\a6e644c363d050c6c90f078f4f0ac66892f60d54\spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aspects\5.0.9.RELEASE\dfb2da4c573391d8e8a482f08bdf4d38398e2bb0\spring-aspects-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.0.5.RELEASE\eaac8a5d73b45400bc88cd7f6b5c99b5f0d5e9b7\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.12.Final\478003e61b056c1f97840ba3e62ff31cdc89597\hibernate-validator-6.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.0.9.RELEASE\c18346caaeb8dc648c4cc01874996fd9fef76664\spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.0.9.RELEASE\1ea3aab93340849313fa74ec626ddaf1fff9ed8e\spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.6\456895fc91bf7180b216fead220373e6278230c9\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.6\ea54f6193d224e5e5732bbd4262327eb465397c2\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.6\129acd77a4b6ee30d62d3a0899b1344c8ec2bff8\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.9.6\cfa4f316351a91bfd95cb0644c6a2c95f52db1fc\jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.2.51\a37c0066df119c02f034bf17159089b588ccc41a\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.51.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.2.51\fa8127e505bff50fec291d0dd619d1bda5c619e0\kotlin-stdlib-1.2.51.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.5.RELEASE\e5588642799e0c0c04638e255c3d3f31ba400ff4\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.0.5.RELEASE\19a4624cbd89a318d10c79f289c6c816043850fb\spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.5.RELEASE\c353e0b9591d0765c687ff0a678478cbebfd5c23\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.0.9.RELEASE\2501e55acb6c2e84667cda3f845d1d00a0dc4e05\spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.0.9.RELEASE\98003b099697fe46b6bdf18c7e3f66d7a1381060\spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-orm\5.0.9.RELEASE\bb9265effd7c903f4cc1c98d16b4188b7827a1cc\spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.9.RELEASE\2f38726ef2f5ecb72af7e915dac43177b01a8f53\spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-commons\2.0.10.RELEASE\64d4e58a2b16b9446d51a2650058d821a5bce98d\spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\5.0.9.RELEASE\d3a13fc3c56bdddd8144a686ed64f0cdb3ad7305\spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.0.9.RELEASE\65f56fdab1bb90ad059e314d2f2f4cf76f9bdbde\spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.0.9.RELEASE\1f9db5ff3a758102c0434cc3457aa47c50c39a4a\spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.0.9.RELEASE\9f9a828936d81afd49a603bda9cc1aed863a0d85\spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\2d998d3d674b172a588e54ab619854d073f555b5\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\ad94df2a28d658a40dc27bbaff6a1ce5fbf04e9b\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\2.7.9\a83113d2c091d0d0f853dad3217bd7df3beb6ae3\HikariCP-2.7.9.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\71e1cff3fcb20d3b3af4f3363c3ddb24d33c6879\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.javax.persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.2.Final\52afb5762c704a6b586e27742470c08f91877fc1\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\3e83394258ae2089be7219b971ec21a8288528ad\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\bfc4d6257dbff7a33a357f0de116be6ff951d849\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\3d5f48f10bbe4eb7bd862f10c0583be2e0053c6\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\f7e631ccf49cfc0aefa4a2a728da7d374c05bd3c\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\af5364cd6679bfffb114f0dec8a157aaa283b76\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.34\5f86906367c2540b21e6aeecc277d2ce9ec939b0\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.34\a038040d68a90397f95dd1e11b979fe364a5000f\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.34\be71a9a5bdd001db7cf97c47429eec0bdd3b7b88\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.34.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.9.6\4e393793c37c77e042ccc7be5a914ae39251b365\jackson-core-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.2.51\e4a9d4b13ab19ed1e6531fce6df98e8cfa7f7301\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.51.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.9.RELEASE\bc3b5aaae53f0bc03647e53ecbd98a05b47a4e90\spring-jcl-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Sistemas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\fec5797a55b786184a537abd39c3fa1449d752d6\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar" com.tksys.tks.TksApplicationKt

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

2018-09-24 11:12:34.463  INFO 6200 --- [           main] com.tksys.tks.TksApplicationKt           : Starting TksApplicationKt on DESKTOP-FJIIFGM with PID 6200 (C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks\out\production\classes started by Sistemas in C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks)
2018-09-24 11:12:34.463  INFO 6200 --- [           main] com.tksys.tks.TksApplicationKt           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-24 11:12:34.525  INFO 6200 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3c153a1: startup date [Mon Sep 24 11:12:34 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-24 11:12:36.244  INFO 6200 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd16ab20] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-24 11:12:36.697  INFO 6200 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-09-24 11:12:36.728  INFO 6200 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-09-24 11:12:36.728  INFO 6200 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2018-09-24 11:12:36.728  INFO 6200 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\composer;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Ruby25-x64\bin;C:\Users\Sistemas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Sistemas\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Sistemas\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;.]
2018-09-24 11:12:36.838  INFO 6200 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-09-24 11:12:36.838  INFO 6200 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2313 ms
2018-09-24 11:12:36.885  INFO 6200 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-09-24 11:12:36.900  INFO 6200 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-24 11:12:36.900  INFO 6200 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-24 11:12:36.900  INFO 6200 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-24 11:12:36.900  INFO 6200 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-24 11:12:37.057  INFO 6200 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-09-24 11:12:37.275  INFO 6200 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-09-24 11:12:37.322  INFO 6200 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-24 11:12:37.353  INFO 6200 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-09-24 11:12:37.416  INFO 6200 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-09-24 11:12:37.416  INFO 6200 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-09-24 11:12:37.463  INFO 6200 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-09-24 11:12:37.572  INFO 6200 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-09-24 11:12:38.041  INFO 6200 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-24 11:12:38.559  WARN 6200 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosController' defined in file [C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks\out\production\classes\com\tksys\tks\controller\Dgis_cat_municipiosController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks\out\production\classes\com\tksys\tks\services\impl\Dgis_cat_municipiosServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tksys.tks.repository.Dgis_cat_municipiosRepository.findAllByCve_entidad(int)! No property cve found for type Dgis_cat_municipios!
2018-09-24 11:12:38.559  INFO 6200 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-24 11:12:38.559  INFO 6200 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-09-24 11:12:38.559  INFO 6200 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-09-24 11:12:38.559  INFO 6200 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-09-24 11:12:38.575  INFO 6200 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-24 11:12:38.575 ERROR 6200 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosController' defined in file [C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks\out\production\classes\com\tksys\tks\controller\Dgis_cat_municipiosController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks\out\production\classes\com\tksys\tks\services\impl\Dgis_cat_municipiosServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tksys.tks.repository.Dgis_cat_municipiosRepository.findAllByCve_entidad(int)! No property cve found for type Dgis_cat_municipios!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.tksys.tks.TksApplicationKt.main(TksApplication.kt:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Sistemas\IdeaProjects\tks\out\production\classes\com\tksys\tks\services\impl\Dgis_cat_municipiosServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dgis_cat_municipiosRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tksys.tks.repository.Dgis_cat_municipiosRepository.findAllByCve_entidad(int)! No property cve found for type Dgis_cat_municipios!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]

    ... 70 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace. And in Java Class names start with an uppercase and do not contain _ but camel case instead.

Comment: Ok I understand, I already made the changes in the classes and I have the controller class in upper case but the same error follows me with  minuscule letter. "Error creating bean with name 'dgisCatMunicipiosController'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you get is pretty clear:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method
>   public abstract java.util.List
>   com.tksys.tks.repository.Dgis_cat_municipiosRepository.findAllByCve_entidad(int)!
>   No property cve found for type Dgis_cat_municipios!

It seems that JPA repository has problems with the _ sign in method signatures.

So please remove all _ in you class, attribute and method names. This should solve your problem.